# No se registra el usuario en la base de datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas noches estoy usando laravel 5.6, y tengo un problema al tratar de registrar un usuario por ajax, pues este no se registra en la base de datos y no me genera ningun error ni en el log. Edite el registro que tiene por defecto Laravel y en el controlador lo tengo asi:

```
public function CrearUsuario(Request $request)
{
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'id_role'=>'required',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'id_funcionario'=>'required'

        ]); 
        $user=new User;
        $user->username=$request->input('username');
        $user->email=$request->input('email');
        $user->id_role=$request->input('id_role');
        $user->id_funcionario=$request->input('id_funcionario');
        $user->estado=$request->input('estado');
        $user->password=$request-> Hash::make(input('password'));
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
             "mensaje"=>"registro correcto." 
        ]);

}
```

y la petición ajax  de esta manera

```
function UsuarioNuevo(){
var id_funcionario=$("#id_funcionario").val();
var username=$("#username").val();
var email= $("#email").val();
var id_role=$("#id_role").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
var route="http://127.0.0.1:8000/NewUser";
var token=$("input[name=_token]").val();
$.ajax({
  url:route,
  headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{
    id_funcionario:id_funcionario,
    username:username,
    email:email,
    id_role:id_role,
    estado:1,
    password:password
  },
  success: function(){
    $("#CrearUsuarioModal").modal("toggle");
    $("#msj-success1").fadeIn();
    $("#msj-success1").fadeOut(5000);

  }
});
```

}

Cuando lo ejecuto el programa corre y no me da ningun tipo de error pero en la base de datos no hay ningun registro

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CrearUsuarioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Crear Usuario
        
          ×

```
    <form id='Formulariouser'>    
                  @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre de usuario') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="username" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Correo Electronico') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="id_role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tipo de Usuario') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="id_role" name="id_role" class="form-control">
                                <option>------Seleccionar------</option>
                                @foreach($roles as $key => $value)
                                <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $key }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contraseña') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirmar contraseña') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UsuarioNuevo();">
                                {{ __('Registrar') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Podrías añadir tu form?

Comment: en vez de $validatedData = $request->validate no debería ser $this->validate($request, [ 'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
        'body' => 'required', ]);

Comment: ¿Obtiene algún error en consola ? está claro que hace falta la confirmación de la clave en  la llamada Ajax si no, no pasará la validación de confirmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay algunos errores  , vamos a ello.

1. Cuando hace la validación por medio de `FormRequest`, añade una regla `confirmed` , lo que espera es que envíe dos valores uno con clave `password` y otro con `password_confirmation`  deberán ser iguales para que pase este validación ,  entonces a su llamada `ajax` debería añadir este campo

   ```
   var password_confirmation =$("#password-confirm").val();
   $.ajax({ ...
      data:{ ...
        password_confirmation: password_confirmation,//falta este campo
   },}
   ```
2. Asegurarse de que en su modelo tiene su array fillable contiene todas los nombres de columnas de su tabla `User`
3. En la linea que asigna la contraseña al nuevo Usuario , tiene un error de sintaxis *$request-> Hash:*, debería aplicar el `Hash::make` antes de asignar debería ser

   ```
   $user->password=Hash::make($request->input('password'));
   ```

Como recomendación evitar la ruta `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/"` *(el problema que sería para luego cambiar el dominio :/ )*,  si está en la vista blade puede utilizar la sintaxis de esta de la siguiente forma

```
var route = '{{ route('NewUser') }}'
```

Claro está que su ruta debe tener este nombre `NewUser` definido

```
Route::post('NewUser','UnControlador@CrearUsuario')->name('NewUser');
```

Además pudiese haber creado el usuario de la forma tradicional con Eloquent , y evitar tantas lineas y para la contraseña crear un [mutador](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) .

```
User::create($request->validated());
```

Otro punto sería, si utilizará Ajax con JQuery sería mejor , definir el `csrf_token` de la [siguiente forma global](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

para esto es necesario añadir el meta, en tu layout

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Con esto para todas las solicitudes `Ajax` no tendrá que definir la clave  `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Al estar dentro del contexto de tu controller, para poder hacer la validación deberías hacer referencia a esta misma clase por medio de `$this`

Tu validación debería verse como:

```
public function CrearUsuario(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

}
```

Por otro lado aunque no muestras tu form, queda claro que debería tener un csrf para validar la acción del usuario; recuerda que al estar en Laravel 5.6 debería ser del modo:

```
<form method="POST">
    @csrf
</form>
```

También te comento que el modo de obtener el token y su valor debería ser así

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

En la parte superior de tu archivo invoca ese namespace de la siguiente manera

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Comment: edite la pregunta y añadi el form y arregle la validación tal cual me indicas pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @ALVAROROBERTOBACARREZAARZAB abre la consola de tu navegador, cuando le des clic al botón de enviar después abre la pestaña en la consola donde dice red y adjunta la captura de pantalla del resultado que esta devolviendo

Comment: @ALVAROROBERTOBACARREZAARZAB te actualicé la respuesta checa lo último que puse

Comment: Hice todo lo que me dicen pero aun no funciona, me pregunto si no funcionara porque estoy tratando de registrar  el usuario estando yo autenticado en el sistema??

Comment: @ALVAROROBERTOBACARREZAARZAB Por favor siga mis modificaciones y debería funcionar _(si no , comentar mi respuesta)_ . No tiene que ver que esté autenticado en el sistema.Tiene errores puntuales que ya detalle en mi respuesta, Saludos.

Comment: @Dev.Joel también tomaré nota de tu respuesta se nota el nivel eres muy preciso

Comment: hice los cambios que me dijiste @Dev.Joel

Comment: revise el log y tus modificaciones hicieron que respondiera de esta forma `local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Hash' not found`

Comment: @ALVAROROBERTOBACARREZAARZAB te anexo en mi respuesta el por que de ese error

Comment: @ALVAROROBERTOBACARREZAARZAB importa en la parte de arriba . `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` , esto debe estar claro , siempre añadir  las clases que se usa.

Comment: Añadí la clase que faltaba y funciono a la perfección les quedo muy agradecido @Dev.Joel ,Alfredo Paz Dios los bendiga